# I started to using mothur version - v.1.36.1-, but I got some error messages (shown below). How I can overcome this?

Tags: mothur

**I start the Mothur Tutorial (https://www.mothur.org/wiki/MiSeq_SOP). But from the beginning, I got some error messages when I create " make.file "in mothur*(Error commands are shown below). I changed parameters but the result was negative. How can I solve this problem?**

```
****mothur > make.file(inputdir=MiSeq_SOP, type=fastq, prefix=stability)
Setting input directory to: MiSeq_SOP/
prefix is not a valid parameter.
The valid parameters are: type, seed, inputdir, and outputdir.
[ERROR]: did not complete make.file.****
```

Comment: The error message is trying to tell you `prefix=stability` is an invalid parameter. Did you try removing that parameter?

Comment: Hi, I tried, but not got any positive results.

Comment: Yes, I did. Even though, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `prefix` parameter **is** [a valid parameter in mothur](https://mothur.org/wiki/make.file/). Personally, I have never encountered a problem with using a prefix for the `make.file` command, but your command should be valid.

You could test if your `inputdir` is specified correctly (the `mothur` error and warning messages are not necessarily the most clear ones). If this works as well, I suggest that you well document this behaviour and [send it to the `mothur` team](https://github.com/mothur/mothur) (in my experience, they are quite responsive and ready to help).